# Casacore not installing on OS X

Tags: python, cmake

I am trying to install casacore on OS X, using:

```
brew install casacore
```

However, I get a CMake error for which I did not find any solution searching online. My output:

```
==> Installing casacore from ska-sa/tap
==> Downloading https://github.com/casacore/casacore/archive/v3.1.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/Thomas/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/3b570ca11953847e1fc2a5b18bc8e9593f9ee563b6aa9a505cb07298fc46514b--casacore-3.1.1.tar.gz
==> Patching
patching file python/CMakeLists-cmake3.12.txt
patching file python3/CMakeLists-cmake3.12.txt
patching file python/Converters/test/CMakeLists.txt
==> cmake ../.. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=
Last 15 lines from /Users/Thomas/Library/Logs/Homebrew/casacore/01.cmake:
-- Looking for python2 specific environment...
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.16.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Python2 (missing: Python2_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS NumPy) (found
  version "2.7.16")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.16.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.16.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:2211 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.16.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPython2.cmake:259 (include)
  python/CMakeLists-cmake3.12.txt:3 (find_package)
  python/CMakeLists.txt:4 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/casacore-20191219-61311-1gqp8fc/casacore-3.1.1/build/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/tmp/casacore-20191219-61311-1gqp8fc/casacore-3.1.1/build/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  https://github.com/ska-sa/homebrew-tap/issues
```

Thank you in advance!

Edit: after installing numpy for Python2, I still get an error, albeit different. The error log is:

```
2019-12-19 23:47:07 +0100

cmake
../..
-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/casacore/3.1.1
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST
-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON
-Wno-dev
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release
-DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS='-undefined dynamic_lookup'
-DCMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS='-undefined dynamic_lookup'
-DBUILD_PYTHON=ON
-DUSE_FFTW3=ON
-DFFTW3_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local
-DUSE_HDF5=ON
-DHDF5_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local
-DUSE_THREADS=ON
-DDATA_DIR=/usr/local/share/casacore/data

-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- Checking whether Fortran compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether Fortran compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether Fortran compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether Fortran compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/local/bin/gfortran
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/local/bin/gfortran  -- works
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether /usr/local/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether /usr/local/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90 -- yes
-- Performing Test HAVE_O_DIRECT
-- Performing Test HAVE_O_DIRECT - Failed
-- Using namespace casacore.
-- Performing Test HAS_CXX11
-- Performing Test HAS_CXX11 - Success
-- Looking for pread
-- Looking for pread - found
-- Looking for pwrite
-- Looking for pwrite - found
-- Found Readline: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib  
-- Could NOT find SOFA (missing: SOFA_LIBRARY) 
-- Found HDF5: debug;/usr/local/lib/libhdf5_hl.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libhdf5.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libsz.dylib;/usr/lib/libz.dylib;/usr/lib/libdl.dylib;/usr/lib/libm.dylib;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libhdf5_hl.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libhdf5.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libsz.dylib;/usr/lib/libz.dylib;/usr/lib/libdl.dylib;/usr/lib/libm.dylib  
-- Found FLEX: /usr/bin/flex  
-- Found BISON: /usr/bin/bison  
-- Looking for Fortran sgemm
-- Looking for Fortran sgemm - not found
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Looking for Fortran sgemm
-- Looking for Fortran sgemm - found
-- Found BLAS: /usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/libopenblas.dylib  
-- Looking for Fortran cheev
-- Looking for Fortran cheev - found
-- A library with LAPACK API found.
-- Found FFTW3: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3f_threads.dylib  
-- Found CFITSIO: /usr/local/lib/libcfitsio.dylib (found suitable version "3.450", minimum required is "3.030") 
-- Found WCSLIB: /usr/local/lib/libwcs.dylib (found suitable version "6.4", minimum required is "4.7") 
-- Found Pthreads: /usr/lib/libpthread.dylib  
-- Looking for python2 specific environment...
-- Found Python2: /usr/local/bin/python2.7 (found version "2.7.16") found components: Interpreter Development NumPy 
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.71.0")  
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:117 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_python-1.71.0/boost_python-config.cmake

  but it set boost_python_FOUND to FALSE so package "boost_python" is
  considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  No suitable build variant has been found.

  The following variants have been tried and rejected:

  * libboost_python37-mt.dylib (3.7, Boost_PYTHON_VERSION=2.7)

  * libboost_python37-mt.a (3.7, Boost_PYTHON_VERSION=2.7)

  * libboost_python37.dylib (3.7, Boost_PYTHON_VERSION=2.7)

  * libboost_python37.a (3.7, Boost_PYTHON_VERSION=2.7)

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:182 (boost_find_component)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.16.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:443 (find_package)
  python/CMakeLists-cmake3.12.txt:17 (find_package)
  python/CMakeLists.txt:4 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/casacore-20191219-71796-1ju2jnd/casacore-3.1.1/build/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/tmp/casacore-20191219-71796-1ju2jnd/casacore-3.1.1/build/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.2.1
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 2fe99bd9823fadea1cf918b1ed8366de7f40d336
Last commit: 11 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: ab4cd9e6434b89a0a8d73a2a22279c39be808908
Core tap last commit: 15 minutes ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CACHE: /Users/Thomas/Library/Caches/Homebrew
HOMEBREW_LOGS: /Users/Thomas/Library/Logs/Homebrew
CPU: quad-core 64-bit kabylake
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3/bin/ruby
Clang: 10.0 build 1001
Git: 2.20.1 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 13
macOS: 10.14.6-x86_64
CLT: 10.3.0.0.1.1562985497
Xcode: 11.0
CLT headers: 10.3.0.0.1.1562985497
XQuartz: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11

HOMEBREW_CC: clang
HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++
MAKEFLAGS: -j4
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/icu4c:/usr/local/opt/openblas:/usr/local/opt/sqlite:/usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/libxml2:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH: /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/cfitsio/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/wcslib/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/isl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/mpfr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/hwloc/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libevent/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/open-mpi/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/fftw/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/xz/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/python/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.14
HOMEBREW_GIT: git
HOMEBREW_SDKROOT: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk
ACLOCAL_PATH: /usr/local/share/aclocal
PATH: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super:/usr/local/opt/cmake/bin:/usr/local/opt/wcslib/bin:/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin:/usr/local/opt/hwloc/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:/usr/local/opt/libevent/bin:/usr/local/opt/open-mpi/bin:/usr/local/opt/fftw/bin:/usr/local/opt/hdf5/bin:/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:/usr/local/opt/gdbm/bin:/usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin:/usr/local/opt/xz/bin:/usr/local/opt/python/bin:/usr/local/opt/numpy/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I have installed all the packages suggested in the casacore page (even the optional ones) and I am just running the simple homebrew command.

Edit 2:
Building from source, I got no errors until the make command. It seems that there is something wrong with the cstdio file:

```
In file included from /Users/Thomas/casacore/casa/stdio.h:33:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:108:9: error: 
      no member named 'FILE' in the global namespace
using ::FILE;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:109:9: error: 
      no member named 'fpos_t' in the global namespace
using ::fpos_t;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:112:9: error: 
      no member named 'fclose' in the global namespace
using ::fclose;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:113:9: error: 
      no member named 'fflush' in the global namespace
using ::fflush;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:114:9: error: 
      no member named 'setbuf' in the global namespace
using ::setbuf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:115:9: error: 
      no member named 'setvbuf' in the global namespace
using ::setvbuf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:116:9: error: 
      no member named 'fprintf' in the global namespace
using ::fprintf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:117:9: error: 
      no member named 'fscanf' in the global namespace
using ::fscanf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:118:9: error: 
      no member named 'snprintf' in the global namespace
using ::snprintf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:119:9: error: 
      no member named 'sprintf' in the global namespace
using ::sprintf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:120:9: error: 
      no member named 'sscanf' in the global namespace
using ::sscanf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:121:9: error: 
      no member named 'vfprintf' in the global namespace
using ::vfprintf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:122:9: error: 
      no member named 'vfscanf' in the global namespace
using ::vfscanf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:123:9: error: 
      no member named 'vsscanf' in the global namespace
using ::vsscanf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:124:9: error: 
      no member named 'vsnprintf' in the global namespace
using ::vsnprintf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:125:9: error: 
      no member named 'vsprintf' in the global namespace
using ::vsprintf;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:126:9: error: 
      no member named 'fgetc' in the global namespace
using ::fgetc;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:127:9: error: 
      no member named 'fgets' in the global namespace
using ::fgets;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:128:9: error: 
      no member named 'fputc' in the global namespace
using ::fputc;
      ~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [casa/CMakeFiles/casa_casa.dir/Arrays/ArrayBase.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [casa/CMakeFiles/casa_casa.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Is python's `numpy` installed on your system? Try `brew install numpy`.

Comment: Yes, it is already installed.

Comment: Were you aware they are [dropping Python 2 support](https://github.com/casacore/casacore/issues/983) in 2020? Perhaps, you should try Python 3?

Comment: Actually I have python3 and use it almost every day; in fact, I have no idea of why it is looking for python2 and not using the python3 stuff.

Comment: It looks like casacore is setup to build only with Python 2 by default, but has an option to build for Python 3. It is unclear what configure options are passed to CMake, as you have not provided the entire build log. So it is hard to say what is going on. One thing you can check is to ensure `numpy` is installed for **Python 2**, which is different than your `numpy` installation for Python 3.

Comment: I installed numpy for python2 and edited the question with the 'new' issue.

Comment: The error logs you provided are hardly enough to understand what is going on. It only shows the last 15 lines, which is pretty useless. Please navigate to the error log `/Users/Thomas/Library/Logs/Homebrew/casacore/01.cmake` and provide the **full** error log in your question post. Also, please provide the *complete* list of configuration/build steps you performed to get to this point, including any *required/optional* packages you installed apriori (as seen [here](https://github.com/casacore/casacore#requirements)).

Comment: Your issues certainly appear to stem from the fact that you have two Python versions installed on your system. While casacore tries to build with Python 2, your `boost` installation is using Python 3, which appears to cause the error messages in your log. FWIW, `boost` has an open bug report on Github for this same issue.

Comment: If you want to keep both Python versions on your system, you may have better luck building casacore from [source](https://github.com/casacore/casacore#compilation). This will give you control over how CMake handles the different Python versions, so it doesn't get confused. You can download from Github and follow the steps to build, including the steps specific to Python 3.

Comment: Thank you. It worked until I got to the make command. CMake showed no errors when I gave it the right options, and now there is something wrong with the cstdio file. I edited the question with the new errors I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the CMakeList.txt file in the casacore directory and change the compiling to Python3 and it worked, as following:

```
#By default build only Python2 bindings
#option (BUILD_PYTHON "Build the python bindings" YES)
option (BUILD_PYTHON3 "Build the python3 bindings" ON)
```